# Next js not too late to read the page url

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to dynamically render a script in next.js depending on the page url. My code in page/app.tsx

```
        <Head>
          <script
          id="script"
          src="www.cookie.com"
          data-cbid={typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.href.includes('localhost') ?
          "XXXXXXXXX" : "YYYYYYYYYY"}
          data-blockingmode="auto"
          type="text/javascript"
          async>
        </script>
      <Head>
```

However, my problem is that next.js knows too late what domain it is on and always returns me "YYYYYYYYYY" because the condition is always wrong. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useRouter hook for next.js to use the current url:
[use-router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router)

Then use the 'isReady' parameter to wait for the object to be ready to use client side.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).